# Improve JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next function:

```
var checkNameLenght = function(name,nameLenght,allowedLenght,defaultName) {
    if((nameLenght <= allowedLenght) && !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name))) {
        return name; 
    }
        else {
            if(opts.debug == true) {
                console.log(name+' is to long or contains special characters / numbers | Please choose a name shorter than '+allowedLenght+' characters or remove any character / number');
            }
            return defaultName;
        }
}
```

What it does, is checking if a certain string is more or less than an allowed length and it also checks if the string contains any special characters or numbers ( except white space ) and if any of the above is confirmed it returns a default string, if not the string.

But this function checks at the same time for the length and regex, `if((nameLenght <= allowedLenght) && !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name))) { ... }`, but I don't want that, I would like it to check first for length and then for regex.

I tried like this:

```
var checkNameLenght = function(name,nameLenght,allowedLenght,defaultName) {
    if(nameLenght <= allowedLenght) {
        return name; 
    }
        else if( !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name)) ){
            return name;

        }
            else {
            if(opts.debug == true) {
                console.log(name+' is to long or contains special characters / numbers | Please choose a name shorter than '+allowedLenght+' characters or remove any character / number');
            }   
            return defaultName;
            }
}
```

But it doesn't work as the first version. What am I doing wrong with the second function ?

Comment: By the way, it's `length`, not `lenght`.

Comment: I know :) I've been mentioned more than a dozen times :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it doesn't work as the first version

Well no, you've changed the logic. You didn't say what exactly is wrong with how the second version is working (or if it is giving you an error?) so it's hard to say exactly what's wrong. But I'll take a guess.

In the second version you first check length, and if that test passes you *immediately* return `name` without doing any further tests. If you need to test the regex too then either use the `&&` syntax from the first version, or nest the second test inside the first if block.

> it also checks if the string contains any special characters or numbers ( except white space ) and if any of the above is confirmed it returns a default string, if not the string.

Actually that's not what the regex you have is doing. This is yours:

```
!(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name))
```

That regex is testing whether `name` contains a white space character followed immediately by any non alphabet character, and then the result of that has the not `!` applied to it. So if your string contains non alphabetic characters that don't immediately follow white space they will not be found. If your goal is to test for any character that is not either alphabet A-Z or white space, anywhere in the string then try this:

```
!(/[^a-z\s]/i.test(name))
```

Or instead of looking for invalid characters just test that the whole string is made up of valid characters:

```
/^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(name)          // note: you don't need the ! for this

//  ^        - match beginning of string
//  [a-z\s]* - match zero or more alphabet or white space characters
//  $        - match end of string
```

Also, you don't need the `nameLenght` parameter, because strings have a length property built in: you can just same `name.length`. (This doesn't stop the function working, obviously, but it is kind of untidy.)

(Also you've misspelled "length", but you seem to have done so consistently in every variable name so it isn't causing a problem. Yet.)

EDIT: new version to work as per your comment:

```
var checkName = function(name, allowedLength, defaultName) {
        if(name.length > allowedLength) {
           console.log("Name is more than allowed length");
           return defaultName;
        }
        if( /[^a-z\s]/i.test(name) ){
           console.log("Name contains special characters or numbers");
           return defaultName;
        }

        // tests passed
        return name;
};
```

Note: you don't need any `else` statements because each `if` returns out of the function. Obviously you can remove the `console.log()` statements I put in, or you can add `if(opt.debug)` statements as in your original.

Comment: Thanks for the regex, I'm not using it often so I don't know to much about it. Well, the purpose of the second version of the function would be: first check if the name is more than the allowed length of the name and if it is return the default name, then check if the name has any special character or number inside it and if it does return the default name, if not return the name, and if the length of the name isn't more than the allowed length then return the name. Hope I'm clear ... :|

Comment: OK, I've edited the end of my answer to reflect what you said in your comment. But the end result as far as what the function returns is exactly the same as your first function (or it would be if you fixed the regex in your function). The only advantage to doing it this new way is if you want to separately log whether the name was too long or had invalid characters - though in fact with logic as described in your comment and shown in my answer it won't even test for invalid characters if the name is too long.

Comment: That is right, I wanted a separate console message for each condition encountered. I tested it and it works fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't really need the `else` there, if your first condition is `true`, the function will return `name` and stop, so a first amelioration would be:

```
var checkNameLenght = function(name,nameLenght,allowedLenght,defaultName) {
    if((nameLenght <= allowedLenght) && !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name))) {
        return name; 
    }

    if(opts.debug == true) {
       console.log(name+' is to long or contains special characters / numbers | Please choose a name shorter than '+allowedLenght+' characters or remove any character / number');
    }
    return defaultName;    
}
```

Now, You want to check the length first, you need to do something like this:

```
var checkNameLenght = function(name,nameLenght,allowedLenght,defaultName) {
    if(nameLenght <= allowedLenght) {
        if( !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name)) ) {
          return name;
        } 
    }

    if(opts.debug == true) {
       console.log(name+' is to long or contains special characters / numbers | Please choose a name shorter than '+allowedLenght+' characters or remove any character / number');
    }
    return defaultName;    
}
```

It is not clear whether you want the `else` to be executed only when the `nameLength` is bigger or when the regex matches too, so you may want to edit my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using some ideas from *nnnnnn*, I think you mean something like this

```
    var checkName = function(name, allowedLength, defaultName) {
        if (name.length > allowedLength) {
            if (opts.debug == true) {
                console.log(name + ' is to long | Please choose a name up to ' + allowedLength + ' characters');
            }   
            return defaultName;
        }
        else if (/[^a-z\s]/i.test(name)) {
            if (opts.debug == true) {
                console.log(name + ' contains special characters or numbers | Please remove any character or number');
            }   
            return defaultName;
        }
        else {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, I was about to answer something similar (although without the superfluous `else if` and `else`). :-)

Comment: @PPvG and @Soufiane: What is your problem with the `else` statements? I disagree strongly: there is no efficiency gained by omitting them, and they group together a set of tests that cover all cases involving a validation; something that isn't obvious if they are split as multiple `if` statements.

Comment: I do not omit them for the sake of efficiency (as there is clearly no gain) but for the sake of readability. I suppose it's personal preference, but I find  `if A, return a`, `if B, return b`, `return c` much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is correct. It won't check simultaneously

in Javascript A && B works as given below

1. first it will check condition A
2. if A is false it will go to else condition
3. if A is true it will check condition B
4. if B is false it will go to else condition
5. if B is also true it will execute the statements inside if

So your first method is correct. 
Like @nnnnnn said problem is with the regular expression and condition. 
As both of the conditions has to be true, it should be

```
if(name.length <= allowedLength && /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(name)) {
    return name;
}else{
    ....
}
```

if you give

```
if(nameLenght <= allowedLenght) {
    return name; 
}else if( !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name)) ){
    return name;
}
else {
    ....
}
```

when either of the first two conditions becomes true, it returns `name`, which is not your requirement.

.